# X11 key names to Linux keycodes

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard, keyboard-event

My program uses the X11 key names like exclam and XF86Forward but internally uses the Linux keycodes found in `/usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h`.
It's just an awk program, and I've written an associative array with the most important keys (`K["F1"] = 59`) to start with, but I was wondering if I could generate it from somewhere.
I found `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/` but my greps didn't seem promising.

Comment: `xmodmap -pk` or `xmodmap -pke` can give you a mapping between keycode and keysym for the X11 server identified by `$DISPLAY`.